# Empty PdfString decodes into a string of 64 ï characters

Tags: pdf, memory-management, itext, itext7, bug-reporting

https://github.com/itext/itext7/blob/develop/CONTRIBUTING.md says this is the place to report itext7 bugs, so there you go.

## Observable behaviour

Using itext7 version 8.0.0

My PDF document includes several instances of `/Span << /ActualText <> >>`

`<>` is valid syntax for a hex-encoded, zero-length `PdfString`; however, it is parsed into a `PdfString` instance with `content` of 128 zero bytes, `hexWriting=true`, and `value` of an empty string.

For this instance, `GetValue()` correctly returns the empty string, but `ToUnicodeString()` is essentially calling `PdfTokenizer.DecodeStringContent(new byte[128], true)` which returns a `byte[64]` having every element set to 239. This is further converted into a string of 64 `ï` characters, which is what `ToUnicodeString()` returns.

As `CanvasTag.GetActualText` calls `ToUnicodeString()`, so it uses the messed-up 64-character string instead of the empty string.

## Reproducer

Using C# immediate window

```
var str = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfString("");
Expression has been evaluated and has no value
str.SetHexWriting(true);
{}
    content: null
    decryptInfoGen: 0
    decryptInfoNum: 0
    decryption: null
    directOnly: false
    encoding: null
    hexWriting: true
    indirectReference: null
    state: 0
    value: ""
str.ToUnicodeString()
"ïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïïï"
```

## Root cause

In https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet/blob/develop/itext/itext.kernel/itext/kernel/pdf/PdfString.cs#L326 :

```cs
        protected internal virtual byte[] EncodeBytes(byte[] bytes) {
            if (hexWriting) {
                ByteBuffer buf = new ByteBuffer(bytes.Length * 2);
                foreach (byte b in bytes) {
                    buf.AppendHex(b);
                }
                return buf.GetInternalBuffer();
            }
```

This creates, for a zero-length `PdfString`, a `new ByteBuffer(0)`.

In https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet/blob/develop/itext/itext.io/itext/io/source/ByteBuffer.cs#L39 :

```cs
        public ByteBuffer(int size) {
            if (size < 1) {
                size = 128;
            }
            buffer = new byte[size];
        }
```

This means that, for a zero-length `PdfString`, the created buffer is a `byte[128]`.

## Suggested fix

Adding `if (bytes.Length == 0) return bytes;` into `EncodeBytes` would do just fine.

Unfortunately, no workaround is possible without modifying itext7 core.

I'm not posting this as a PR because my PRs at https://github.com/itext/i7n-pdfocr/pulls haven't received any attention since 2020. Hopefully, shaped as a bug report, it may get a bit more attention from itext7 team.

Comment: I suspect their suggestion to ask about bugs on StackOverflow is intended for people who can't get something to work, and think it's a bug clogging up their bug tracker. You actually have a real bug - so I would file it as a bug report.